# how to add an object with two pairs to an array that has a key and values that are same as the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need to build an array based on server data. I get the data as an object like this:

```
{name: "test", hobby: "test"}
```

and my array that I want to add this object to looks like this:

```
[0: {name: "test1", hobby: "test1"}, 1 : {name: "test2", hobby: "test2"}]
```

output should be:

```
[0: {name: "test1", hobby: "test1"}, 1 : {name: "test2", hobby: "test2"}, 2 : {name: "test", hobby: "test"}]
```

How do I add the element to the array? Push did not work in this case. I need to add the key to the element and then add it to the end of array but I don't know how.
Please let me know what are the options.Thanks.

Comment: This is an invalid array structure. [ {key: "value"}, {key: "value} ] will have no trouble with push.

Comment: Ummm honestly, I didn't get it. Are you getting that desired output from the browser's console? because those keys `0 and 1` are the indexes of an array.

Comment: so `array = [{name: "test1", hobby: "test1"}, {name: "test2", hobby: "test2"}]` ... to add `{name: "test", hobby: "test"}` to the end of that array, you would use `array.push({name: "test", hobby: "test"})`

Comment: yes it is from console.

Comment: I think your confusion might be that `[].push({}) == 1`. The result of `push` is the new length of the array. If this is what's tripping you up, consider `a = []; a.push({}); a`

Comment: No that was not the issue I tried. I will post my answer if I get it right other ways.

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda X. I was doing it like :
array.push(element) which was wrong because it adds it like an object.
But I should have done it like this:
array.push({element.name: "test", element.hobby: "test"}).
You gave me the hint.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add key, you should use object.
like

```
let obj = {};
function addData(){
    let length = Object.keys(obj).length
    temp = {name:"test"+(length+1),hobby:"test"+(length+1)}
    obj[length]= temp;
    console.log(obj);
}
```